# What's wrong with the following Code

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the following snippets of code. Please check the errors I am getting at the end.

```
#include "Tree.h"

template <class T>
CNode<T>* CNode<T>::GetChild(const T& kData)
{
    for( std::vector< CNode >::iterator it = m_vChildren.begin(); it!= m_vChildren.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it== kData)
        {
           return &(*it);
        }
    }
}
```

Tree.h (Header file):

```
#include "../include_m.h"
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class CNode
{
 public:
    CNode(const T& kData)
    {
        m_Data = kData;
    }

    void AddChildNode(const CNode& kcChildNode);
    void DeleteChildNode(const T& kData);
    void GetChildNode(const T& kData) const;
    void Print();

 private:
    T                       m_Data;
    std::vector<CNode>      m_vChildren;

    CNode * GetChild(const T& kData);
};
```

This fails to compile with the following errors:

```
g++ -o tree Tree.cpp 
Tree.cpp: In member function ‘CNode<T>* CNode<T>::GetChild(const T&)’:
Tree.cpp:12: error: expected `;' before ‘it’
Tree.cpp:12: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Don't you need `for (std::vector< CNode<T> >::iterator it = ...`?  And what is `m_vChildren` declared as?

Comment: I had that before, but removed it. Compiler doesn't complain, so thought it is OK.

Comment: You can't store a vector of type `CNode` since `CNode` isn't actually a class; your compiler is telling you the declaration of `it` is not valid, therefore `it` was not declared.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Added the Tree.h code as well. Please check it out.

Comment: @Jimmy What do you mean "CNode isn't actually a class" ?

Comment: `CNode` is not a class; at compile time template classes are split into each individual time `T` is called. You can't go around passing template classes without telling (or inferring) `T`. `T` can only be inferred from template *functions*, not template *classes*.

In short, `CNode` cannot be returned or passed into anywhere. And furthermore, you should not be using `.cpp` files for template classes. They must all be inlined (declaration and definition in the `.h`).

Comment: All you're missing is a `typename` before `std::vector< CNode >::iterator`

Comment: @Yaser, I get the same error.

Comment: @Jimmy, you mean to say I need to use CNode<T> explicitly ? If so, I tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're missing is a `typename` before `std::vector< CNode >::iterator`. Since `CNode<T>::GetChild` is a templated context, the compiler can't know whether `std::vector< CNode >::iterator` is a type or a value member. You could for instance have a template specialization of `std::vector<CNode<int> >` where `iterator` is defined as a class field. You need to use the `typename` keyword to resolve this ambiguity.

On a relevant note, there's an even trickier situation where you need the `template` keyword, and it might be worth mentioning here, consider:

```
template <class T>
struct C {
   template <class U>
   void memfunc();
};

template <class T>
void func() {
   C<T> c;
   c.template memfunc<int>();
}
```

You need the odd `template` keyword in the last line there, since due to a similar reason to your problem, the compiler can't know that the member is in fact a template method in all specializations of the class `C`. The error messages you get with this is also quite odd and  they puzzle me every time.

The other answers also have a relevant point about having a template definition in a `.cpp` file. You should probably follow their advice and move the definition to a `.h` file. However, there actually are circumstances where you want a template definition in a `.cpp` file. For instance, it might be that the method is only used in the same `.cpp` file. Or you might want to take control of what types you want the templated member function to be instantiated with using explicit instantiation. You would achieve this with:

```
template class CNode<int>; // explicitly instantiate CNode<int> 
template CNode<double>* CNode<double>::GetChild(const double& kData); // explicitly instantiate only the GetChild method for CNode<double>
```

This way, you won't have to recompile every `.cpp` file that includes `tree.h` whenever you make a change to the implementation of the `GetChild` method.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, this `typename` issue gets me all the time as well, it just seems so obvious to a human eye, but not to the vigilant eye of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use a `.cpp` file with a template class. Everything must be in the `.h`.
2. You're using references to `CNode` in your header to indicate return types, values placed inside `std::vector`s and parameters. These *all* have to be changed to `CNode<T>`.

---

This is because `CNode` does not exist as a class in itself, but rather a *template* for classes to be created from at compile time. For every type placed inside `<T>`; a new class is created at compile time.

Meaning `CNode<X>` is not the same class as `CNode<Y>`, and `CNode` does not exist at all in the binary/executable.

This means that you can *never* reference CNode, or its members, without providing a value for `<T>`.

Comment: Agreed. That was not the issue.

Comment: That is your issue, using `typename` in this context is a workaround, and said keyword was made to be used when dealing with `typedef`s in template classes to determine *when* they get expanded.

Comment: How is using `typename` a workaround? He would need to use it even if he moved the implementation to the `.h` file.

Comment: I agree with @enobayram. There is an ambiguity there for the compiler and hence using the keyword typename makes sense.

Comment: Using `typename` is masking an obvious ambiguity in your code. The ambiguity being that you're talking about something that *isn't* a type as if it *were* one; `typename` is tantamount to a `typedef`.

You could just as easily insert `typename CNode<T> CNode;` at the top of your class definition and achieve the same result. However, this makes the code harder to read. The fact you're resorting to inserting an extra `typename` keyword should be a further indicator that something "smells" wrong with the code.

Using `CNode<T>` consistently would remove the problem itself, not just hide it.